# How to load ajax lightbox using Fancybox3 & jquery without data-attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox, fancybox-3

A question from noob.

I have a link

```
<a href="/page.html">Link</a>
```

I have a page.html

```
<div id="one">
<div id="two">
something
</div>
</div>
```

How to load #two div using Fancybox3 ajax lightbox **without** changing link through adding data-attributes like "data-fancybox" or "href=" to "data-src=" override.

*Sorry for my englando :)*

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
Show your attempts, e.g. the code which works but does not match your "without" requirement. Your *English* by the way is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom click event to your link and then open fancybox manually.

Comment: Yes, but data-selector doesn't work with this method, so I see in lightbox full page, not only #two div.

Comment: No idea what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it should look like this:

```
$.fancybox.open({
    src: '/page.html',
    type: 'ajax',
    opts : {
        selector : 'two'
    }
})
```

If you don't want to modify your link you need custom click event. You could use $(this) or $(e.target) to get element you clicked on to get .attr('href') with your link.